# Estimate BigDecimal Calculation time

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

I have made a scientific calculator which uses BigDecimal. It has a particularly resource-hungry feature, factorial. Now, typing ANY number fires up the calculation.Depending on the device that this code is being run on , the answer is displayed at different times. Typing huge values like 50000! (factorial) causes the device to freeze up. **Is there anyway to pre-calculate the time that each BigDecimal operation takes?** these factors should vary with processing speed, RAM etc.

Comment: Roughly, a multiplication will take time proportional to the square of the length of the numbers to multiply.

Comment: Unit of time? Milliseconds ?

Comment: Does not matter, I did not say what the factor of proportionality is. It depends on your hardware.

Comment: so please try to answer my question a bit more clearly. I didnt get  it

Comment: runtime = c * square(L); c is a constant that depends on your hardware. You can determine it by making some measurements.

Answer (score 1):

For sufficiently large *n*, use [*Stirling's approximation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to display an immediate result for *n!*, while the more precise calculation proceeds in the background.

Comment: I just gave an example example of factorial, it can be other operations as well

Comment: Sadly, I know of no general solution. As platforms vary, you may have to ask the user to run a benchmark to gather empirical timing data; NetBeans `Calibration` command is an example. Humans tolerate waiting better when they can see progress, do other things in the interim, and cancel an improvident operation.